# Contextual filter in Views for taxonomy browsing

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm having a problem with setting filter value from the URL. What I want to do is to list all terms in a taxonomy node, so I list all terms whose parent ID equals what's provided by URL. I have the relation set, I have the contextual filter set, but unfortunately when I enter %1 as the parent term ID value to be matched by the filter, it's treated literally and returns nothing. That's because no term has the ID of '%1'. However, when I expose the filter and type in the term ID, works as expected.

How do I use the placeholders in the filter definition?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  List your fields, and filters, your path and any contextual filters you have set up and I should be able to help.

Comment: the setup can be as trivial as: path = taxonomy/term/%/list and I want to show only those taxonomy term whose parent term's tid == %1. I have set up (a) the contextual filter to capture the % in the url as the term id, (b) a relation to parent term (c) a filter criterion that says term id = %1, using the parent relation. While the view is executed, the (c) filter is filled with '%!' instead of the value captured from the url.

Comment: I've run into a site problem I need to address ASAP.  In the meantime, Can you add an export of your view to your question?  I am trying to duplicate your problem, but I am not sure I've got the same setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that moment I have messed with my views to a fubar state. But looks like I pinpont the rule of thumb that I haven't heard anywhere: when you set up a context filter, eg. for "Content: nid", you don't add it to the regular filter list on the left hand side. And you don't have to bother with %-style placeholders.
At any rate, thanks JoeS for your readiness to help. I bet you will have a bunch of chances to help me out, as I seem to attract all kind of Drupal surprises ;-)